# Displaying an image in PHP from MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display an image using php. The image is stored in MYSQL table. I am able to retrieve the information from mysql in my php code, but i am having trouble displaying the image.

```
   $db_link = mysql_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password) or die("Could not connect to $host_name");

   mysql_select_db("gameportal") or die("Could not select database $db_name");

   $query = "select * from gamesinfo;";
   $result = mysql_query($query, $db_link) or die("Could not select");

   $Row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

   echo "$Row[0]<br>";

   echo "$Row[1]<br>";

   echo "<img src="$Row[7]" class="body" alt="" /> <br>";//image

   echo "$Row[5]<br>";
```

Row 7 contains the location of the image (in this case a weblink). When i try to display the webpage, the page is blank, nothing shows, but when i remove that line with the pic, the webpage shows with the remaining info. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post an example HTML output of the image. Will give a bit more insight.

Comment: its a blank white page that shows up, nothing more.

Comment: Apologies. Misread that.

Comment: Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. Object oriented will save you typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
echo "<img src="$Row[7]" class="body" alt="" /> <br>";
```

You use unquoted double quotes inside double quotes ;-). Try

```
echo "<img src='$Row[7]' class='body' alt='' /> <br>";
```

**EDIT**

The point is **not** the double quotes inside double quotes, but **unquoted** double quotes inside double quotes - this should work as well:

```
echo "<img src=\"$Row[7]\" class=\"body\" alt=\"\" /> <br>";
```

Comment: i think it should actually be `echo "<img src='".$Row[7]."' class='body' alt='' /> <br>";`

Comment: @lhoppe this should be the same!

Comment: @EugenRieck thanks, that worked, didn't realize i needed to sue single quotes.

Comment: @A22asin you just can't mix them up. If you echo with double quotes, use single quotes within, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I missed this the first time but:

```
<?php

$db_link = mysql_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password) or die("Could not connect to $host_name");

mysql_select_db("gameportal")bor die("Could not select database $db_name");
```

You've got bor instead of or. Make sure to turn PHP errors on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Images is a directory where the images are stored.

$dir="images/";

**

```
echo "<img src='$dir/$row[image]' width=100px height=100px>";
```

**

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer.... but a small piece of advice. I have written an answer because I don't have the reputation for commenting. You can turn on error reporting with this line at the top of php script.

```
    error_reporting(-1);
```

Such kinds of errors would be displayed on screen and you would be able to debug yourself. When your work is done you can simply do this...

```
    error_reporting(0);
```

Refer this link: [PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)